# WordPress - How to get the index number of the posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, shortcode

I was trying to get the index number of the posts which belong to a specific category.

I tried to create a shortcode to achieve but no luck, it returns "1" for all posts.

```
// Get the current post index number by [manset_post_index]
function manset_post_index() {
$manset_posts = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'              => 'post',
            'post_status'            => 'publish',
            'category_name'          => 'manset',
            'update_post_term_cache' => false,
            'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
            'cache_results'          => false,
        ) );

    if ( $manset_posts->have_posts() ) : $manset_posts->the_post();
        $thenumber = $manset_posts->current_post + 1;
    endif;
   return $thenumber;
   }
add_shortcode( 'manset_post_index', 'manset_post_index' );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I'm using this shortcode [mycategory_post_index] in a layer of Post Based Revslider. The frontend result should be like "3" which means: the 3rd (3rd post in descending order) post in that specific category.

Comment: I’m seeing two short code tags, are they nested or independent of each other? Please post how they are used

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for the reply, I simplified the question and added a footnote.